# Как работает этот пример очереди в языке Lua?

Tags: lua

Есть пример реализации очереди из книги. Но я не пойму почему при помещении первого элемента происходит list.first - 1. Получается поле first будет расти в отрицательную сторону с каждым разом (-1, -2, -3 и т.д.) При этом функция (List.popfirst) вернет последний элемент, а не первый помещенный. Может быть я не правильно понимаю что должен делать этот код на самом деле?

```
List = {}
function List.new ()
return {first = 0, last = -1}
end
```

Теперь мы можем вставлять и удалять элементы с обоих концов за
постоянное время:

```
function List.pushfirst (list, value)
local first = list.first - 1
list.first = first
list[first] = value
end

function List.pushlast (list, value)
...
end

function List.popfirst (list)
local first = list.first
if first > list.last then error("list is empty") end
local value = list[first]
list[first] = nil -- чтобы разрешить сборку мусора
list.first = first + 1
return value
end

function List.poplast (list)
...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

pushfirst вставляет элемент перед первым - тоесть он становится первым.
popfirst забирает первый элемент.

Тут намекается на List.pushlast и List.poplast реализация которых тривиальна.

Суть класса в том что можно вставлять и спереди и сзади, доставать также можно и спереди и сзади.